# htaccess 401 redirect is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write an htaccess code to redirect to a specific page. But it is not working now. Please see the full htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)$ job.php?j=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameIndustryJobs.php?i=$1&c=$2&p=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w',]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameCatagoryJobs.php?c=$1&s=$3&p=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameCityJobs.php?c=$1&cn=$4&p=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameQualificationJobs.php?q=$1&cn=$5&p=$6
ErrorDocument 401 sorry.php

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put `[L]` at the end of every RewriteRule line you have. Flag `L` means Last which indicated end of a rule to Apache.